# What is the logic Graph API uses to return result set

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to use the following Graph API using the graph explorer in our application: https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/workingWith

https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/graph-explorer

What is the logic to derive the result set? 
For example, does the API look at my:

- Email activity
- Skype List
- Office Delve
- AAD users
- my manager / skip level managers directs

Also if I retrieve the results by varying the top parameter, what is the logic of retrieving the results:

```
$top=10
```

vs

```
$top=50
```

Answer (score 0):

Working with is a people to people relationship, calculated based on: Public information like People followings in SharePoint, Organizational structure, Distribution List peers, and so forth. And private or cached information like the Recipient Cache from Exchange, Co-authors of SharePoint/OneDrive documents, elevated peers (people that you have looked at and clicked on their info or boards). All of these relationships feed ranking and relevance models that calculate the people you are working with. The results are ranked and using top parameter you can get to that number of records as they are ordered in the rank. Going forward we are folding workingWith API with the People API, so I recommend you look into that and use it instead: https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/api-reference/beta/api/person_get

Comment: Thanks much Yina for the quick response